# CSS Property 'hyphens' not working on other machine with same browser version

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have created a layout in which the CSS property 'hyphens: auto' is used for automatic word breaks.
On my computer with Chrome (v91) the word breaks are displayed, but not on the client, who uses the same browser version. The customer is however in a company network, if that plays a role.
Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

https://caniuse.com/?search=hyphens

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens#browser_compatibility says regarding Chrome, _“auto value is only supported on macOS and Android and for languages the OS provides hyphenation for.”_ - so it might simply be a case of their OS not providing the necessary ruleset for hyphenation in the language in question.

Comment: I can confirm that it works on both macOS and Windows. Have you set the `lang` attribute correctly ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any information where the browser pulls the ruleset for this information?